# Ninja Form is not working whan user is logged out in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I have a e-commerce word-press website using Ninja Form plugin. When user is logout from the site the ninja form not submitted and when user is login in site then Ninja Form is working fine. Why Happening this issue in my site. 
Site link is https://www.helserbrothers.com/register/

[image]